# R function for plotting x number of variables

Tags: r, function, plot

I am attempting to write a function that will be inserted into a larger script. The aim of this function is to accept any number of input variables and then plot them accordingly:

```
Plot_funct <- function(FigFolder,var1,var2,var3,...){

nargin <- length(as.list(match.call())) -1
```

}

This is where I'm starting from, here we have FigFolder which is the path of where the figures should be saved (as .pdf), I define 'nargin' which specifies the number of input arguments, and then I was planning on looping through each of the arguments (var1,var2, etc) and plot accordingly. The main concern I have is how do you set up a function to allow any number of inouts?

Comment: Depending on what you need to plot exactly, facetting in `ggplot2` might also be very interesting. This works particulary well if your plots are effectively the same (x and y var), but you have plots per time interval, or some other categorical variable.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, your answer was great. I have added a new post which highlights some of the other constraints I have come across with developing this function. I did not want to mask this answer by adding further questions to the OP. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118855/plotting-routine-for-n-number-of-arguments-in-r

Comment: also answered on linked page

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118855/plotting-routine-for-n-number-of-arguments-in-r/16127025#16127025

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is much easier is to just provide a list of these variables:

```
plot_funct = function(FigFolder, variable_list, ...) {
   for(variable in variable_list) {
      # Make plot here
   }
})
```

or a bit more R like:

```
plot_variable = function(variable, ...) {
   # Make plot here
})

plot_funct = function(FigFolder, variable_list, ...) {
   lapply(variable_list, plot_variable, ...)
})
```

You could also stick to the separate variables, and use `...`:

```
plot_function = function(..., FigFolder) {
   variable_list = list(...)
   # and use any of the two strategies given above, I'll use lapply
   lapply(variable_list, plot_variable)
})
```

Note that this is more pseudo-code than real R code, but it illustrates the general strategy.