# plotting routine for n number of arguments in r

Tags: r, function, plot

I have the following parameters that I wish to plot:

```
weight <- c(102,20,30,04,022,01,220,10)
height <- c(102,20,30,04,022,01,220,10)

catg <- c(102,20,30,04,022,01,220,10)
catg <- matrix(height,nrow = 2)
```

and these should be plotted in a pdf file saved in the path:

```
FigureFolder <- "C:\\..."
```

I am attempting to write a function that takes n number of input parameters and saves them into a file (in this case this file if defined by FigureFolder). I have the following function:

```
    Plotting_Function <- function( ...,FigureFolder){

      # find the number of input arguments
      nargin <- length(as.list(match.call())) -1  
      nargin <- nargin - 2

      variable_list <- list(...)
      variable_list <- variable_list[1:nargin]

      for (i in 1:length(variable_list)){
        if (variable_list[i] == "catg")   

routine 1 will go here

        if(variable_list[i] != "catg")

routine 2 will go here

      }
    }
```

So, from here I am trying to make the function work so thatif the variable 'catg' is inserted into the function the plotting routine will follow routine 1 (contour in my case), otherwise it will follow routine 2 (line plot in y case).

However, the problem I'm having is that variable_list returns a number and not the name of the variable inserted e.g.

```
Plotting_Function <- function(weight,height,catg,FigureFolder)
```

variable_list will be 1,2, and 3 not weight, height, and catg, therefore I cannot use the if statement I have shown. Could anyone suggest a method to make this work?

Comment: You do not use `nargin` in the function, apart from determining it.

Comment: what do you mean? nargin is the number of input arguments which is the used to define the number of variables for plotting

Comment: The `[1:nargin]` part is superfluous I believe, you just print all variables that are contained in `...`, no need for subsetting.

Comment: but if I return list(...) it contains 4 variables, the 3 I inserted into the function and FigFolder.

Comment: That is because you named argument is called `FigureFolder` not `FigFolder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, this would work:

```
Plotting_Function <- function( ... , FigureFolder) {

  v_names <- as.list(match.call())
  #variable_list <- list(...)
  variable_list <- v_names[2:(length(v_names)-1)]

  for (i in 1:length(variable_list)) {

    if (variable_list[i] == "catg") print("category") # example

      #routine 1 will go here

    if (variable_list[i] != "catg") print(as.character(variable_list[i][[1]])) # example

      #routine 2 will go here

  }
}
```